# Sending messages from UWP to socket.io

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, socket.io, uwp

I have a simple node socket.io server and a C# UWP app.
I want to send simple messages from the app to the server, but it seems the message is not in the right format/protocol/something.
I tried to get the formatting correct, but i don't know how to do it.

`app.js`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('CLIENT CONNECTED')

  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log('socket msg')
    console.log(msg)
}
```

when i fire a message from [socket.io tester](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/socketio-tester/cgmimdpepcncnjgclhnhghdooepibakm), the console shows

```
socket msg
dwadwadwada
```

(just as it should be)

debug output:

```
 engine:socket packet +1ms
  socket.io-parser decoded 2["message","dwadwadwada"] as {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["message","dwadwadwada"]} +0ms
  socket.io:socket got packet {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["message","dwadwadwada"]} +0ms
  socket.io:socket emitting event ["message","dwadwadwada"] +0ms
  socket.io:socket dispatching an event ["message","dwadwadwada"] +0ms
```

now if i send a string from my UWP app (removed try/catches and exception handling for brevity)

```
string msg = "test";
await sendMessage(msg);

private async Task sendMessage(string message)
{
    this.socket = new MessageWebSocket();
    socket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
    socket.MessageReceived += socketMsgReceived;
    await this.socket.ConnectAsync(uri);
    Debug.WriteLine("CONNECTED TO " + uri);

    DataWriter messageWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);

    messageWriter.WriteString(message);
    await messageWriter.StoreAsync();
}
```

, the message is sent (no errors) and the server seems to get *something*, but it is not recognized as message.

```
 engine:ws received "test" +6s
  engine:socket packet +1ms
  engine:ws closing +1ms
  socket.io:client client close with reason parse error +0ms
  socket.io:socket closing socket - reason parse error +1ms
```

i tried formatting the message as 
`{message = "test"}` or even `42["message","test"]` with no effect, even though the latter at least gave me

```
  engine:ws received "42["message" = "test"]" +4s
  engine:socket packet +0ms
  socket.io-parser decoded 2["message" = "test"] as {"type":4,"data":"parser error"} +0ms
  socket.io:client no socket for namespace undefined +1ms
```

I'm pretty sure this is an easy fix, but i just can't find out how to do it..
do i have to convert it to a special type? JSONify it somehow?
I don't want any fancy stuff, just sending a

```
{message: "hi"}
```

or maybe (after the first one works)

```
{message: {text: "hi", additionalStuff: "ho"}}
```

I'd appreciate any help :)
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show me the connect URI? And did you must use Socket.IO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out what was the problem...

i really had to build the websocket string by hand, as (how i noticed) socket.io is not actually the same as websockets, but just a wrapper.

so i had to build a JSON string from scratch with info from [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol).

my final string looked something like

```
 "42[\"mess\"," +
 "{\"id\": \"" + id + "\", " +
 "\"name\": \"" + name + "\"}]";
```

with a lot of escaped quotes... i didn't really understand why it's **42** instead of "4" like the docs say for message, but i found out that that's what is actually sent, so i just used it (it works)

the above message is parsed by

```
socket.on('mess', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg) 
}
```

as

```
{id: blah, name: bleh}
```

Comment: I have been looking for this solution since yesterday. Thank you so much!